# extract title xpath if code xpath is present

Tags: php, xpath

i am trying to extract coupon codes and if the code is present then get the corresponding title too but unable to do so.

in the code below i am able to extract the coupon codes correctly but how do i get the corresponding title to be extracted oo. as you can see in the link some titles don't have coupon codes...

```
<?php



$html = file_get_contents('http://www.grabon.in/abof-coupons/'); //get the html returned from the following url

$mydoc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors

if(!empty($html)){ //if any html is actually returned

    $mydoc->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html

    $my_xpath = new DOMXPath($mydoc);

    //get all the codes

    $my_code = $my_xpath->query('//*[@class="coupon-click"]//a//small');
    if($my_code->length > 0){
        foreach($my_code as $row){      
            $my_row = $my_xpath->query('//*[@class="h3_click"]');
            echo $code->nodeValue . "<br/>";

        }
    }
}


?>
```

thanx fusion3k the code works perfectly but using ur code i tried for different url as below and get the error Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('http://official.deals/ebay-coupons?coupon-id=1055981&h=ed68f1b2a5b28471ecf9584734d65742&utm_source=coupon_page&utm_medium=deal_reveal&utm_campaign=od_deal_click#ebay1055981'); //get the html returned from the following url

$mydoc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors

if(empty($html)) die("EMPTY HTML");

    $mydoc->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html

    $my_xpath = new DOMXPath($mydoc);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $result = array();

    $nodes = $my_xpath->query( '//div[@data-rowtype="1"]' );
    foreach( $nodes as $node )
    {
        $title  = $my_xpath->query( 'div[@class="cop-head"]/h4', $node )->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $found = $my_xpath->query( 'div[@class="cop-head"]/div/input/value', $node );
        $coupon = ( $found->length ) ? $found->item(0)->nodeValue : '' ;
        $result[] = compact( 'title', 'coupon' );
    }


echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want retrieve also boxes without coupon, you have to proceed in a different way: retrieve all boxes and, for each box, find if a coupon code exists.

Init an array to store results:

```
$result = array();
```

Search for boxes ( `<li>` nodes with class “coupon-list-item ” ):

```
$nodes = $my_xpath->query( '//li[@class="coupon-list-item "]' );
#                                                        ↑ pay attention!
```

Then analyze each node through a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach( $nodes as $node )
{
```

Match titles:

```
    $title    = $my_xpath->query( 'div/b[@class="h3_click"]', $node )->item(0)->nodeValue;
    #                              ┊                            ┊
    # No starting slashes, pattern is node-relative             ┊
    #          Second optional xpath->query parameter define the search context
```

Then search for coupons, if it exists:

```
    $found    = $my_xpath->query( 'div[@class="coupon-actions"]/div/a/small', $node );
    $coupon   = ( $found->length ) ? $found->item(0)->nodeValue : '' ;
```

At the end, you can add a sub-array to `$result` using the *fabulous* downplayed [`compact`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) function:

```
    $result[] = compact( 'title', 'coupon' );
}
```

If you want, you can also add related coupons in similar way:

```
$nodes = $my_xpath->query( '//div[@class="related-coupons"]/*/div[@class="col-sm-8"]' );
foreach( $nodes as $node )
{
    $title  = $my_xpath->query( 'div/div[@class="coupon-title"]', $node )->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $found = $my_xpath->query( 'div/div[@class="coupon-click"]/a/small', $node );
    $coupon = ( $found->length ) ? $found->item(0)->nodeValue : '' ;
    $result[] = compact( 'title', 'coupon' );
}
```

At the end, `$result` looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Upto 80% OFF + Extra Rs. 500 OFF On Rs 1495 - All Users
            [coupon] => ABOFBMF500C
        )
    (...)
    [14] => Array
        (
            [title] => Fresh Arrivals on Women & Men Collection
            [coupon] => 
        )
    (...)
)
```

<kbd>**[phpFiddle demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4f1p-h0jg)**</kbd>

Comment: but is there anyway instead of writing all to the array i can skip when its empty?

Comment: Obviously there is it! Can you figure how? It's not too hard... Take a look inside the loop: `$coupon = ( $found->length ) ? $found->item(0)->nodeValue : '' ;` it the same as `if( $found->length ) { $coupon = ...; } else { ... }`... Let me know if you find the way!